# DataGrid ContextMenu MenuItems are sometimes disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a `DataGrid` and I do not know, why the `MenuItems` of `ContextMenu` are [sometimes enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6KbZ.png) and [sometimes disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyKSk.png).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Command="Paste" />
            <MenuItem Command="Delete" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

What can be the cause for that? I did not find any code, which is responsible for setting the [`ICommand.CanExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) or the [`MenuItem.IsEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx).

Please tell me which information I still need to provide.

---

**@Maverik:** I do not wrote any code for those three standard .NET commands:

- [`ApplicationCommands.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.delete.aspx)
- [`ApplicationCommands.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy.aspx)
- [`ApplicationCommands.Paste`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.paste.aspx)

Comment: Yes, IMHO you should provide mode details

Comment: Without an MCVE, this is very hard to answer question. My *guess* would be that it depends on the underlying element that is getting the right click activated. You should add the at least one of the Commands code to question (assuming all three basically have same code besides the specific function).

Comment: @Maverik - I have updated my question with a comment for you.

Comment: I had a feeling you were using those. Which means you're at the mercy of CommandManager and yup this sort of thing happens with automatic re-queries. I'd love to know why this happens too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MenuItems are built-in WPF commands. Accordingly to MSDN documentation their implementation depends on control where commands were triggered and in your case from the state of DataGrid(row selected or not etc.).

> ...The implementation logic is bound to the command with a
>   CommandBinding. For example, if the Close command is executed on a
>   control, the logic which performs the Close command may not be
>   provided by the control, so the application writer will be responsible
>   for writing the logic that determines how the control will handle the
>   command.
>
> Many controls do provide implementation logic for many of the commands
>   in the command library. For example, the TextBox class provides logic
>   for the Paste, Cut, Copy, Undo, and Redo commands.

See [ApplicationCommands Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx).

You can impact your ContextMenu by putting in XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Copy" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
</DataGrid.CommandBindings>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;//put here your logic
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I really found out this solution some minutes ago :-D This is definitely the answer to my question.